# Не работает терминал в Visual Studio, terminated with exit code: 259

Tags: visual-studio, консоль

Не работает терминал в Visual Studio, ни Git, ни cmd, ни powershell.   Никакой.
Ошибка:
`The terminal process "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" terminated with exit code: 259`
В свойствах Visual Studio режим совместимости не указан.
Помогите.